# Why use the `transient` keyword in java?

Tags: java, serialization, keyword, transient, modifier

I have an issue related to the `transient` keyword's use before the `private` modifier in java .

variable declaration:

```
transient private ResourceBundle pageResourceBundle;
```

My class looks like this :

```
public class LoginViewModel extends AbstractViewModel {

    transient private ResourceBundle pageResourceBundle;

    @AfterCompose
    public void afterCompose(@ContextParam(ContextType.VIEW) Component view) {
        initializeLoginValues();
        boolean timeout = BooleanUtils.toBoolean(getHttpServletRequest().getParameter("timeout"));
        if (timeout) {
            Messagebox.show(pageResourceBundle.getText("MSG_SESSION_HAS_EXPIRED_PLEASE_LOGIN"), pageResourceBundle.getText("LABEL_ALERT"),
                    Messagebox.OK, Messagebox.ERROR);
        }
        view.getPage().setTitle(CsdcLicence.get().getApplicationName());
    }
```

I have some questions.

1.why use the `transient` keyword before a private variable?

2.what is the purpose of using this keyword?

Comment: The link you provided answers both your questions.  What is your doubt?  What was not already covered?

Comment: @PeterLawrey  Edit  my question pls see my class its not implements serialize

Comment: It is possible your class gets serialized by the library you are using or  `transient` could be used by the library you are using with the model for another purpose.  It might display all your fields in the view except the `transient` ones.  You would have to read the documentation for the library you are using.

Comment: Could someone please explain WHY would we want to intentionally lose the object over the network? Any examples?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

transient variables are never serialized in java.

It marks a member variable not to be serialized when it is persisted to streams of bytes. When an object is transferred through the network, the object needs to be 'serialized'. Serialization converts the object state to serial bytes. Those bytes are sent over the network and the object is recreated from those bytes. Member variables marked by the java transient keyword are not transferred, they are lost intentionally.

please have a look at what [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) is.? and also refer [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/transient)

Example

```
public class Foo implements Serializable
{
  private String saveMe;
  private transient String dontSaveMe;
  private transient String password;
  //...
}
```

In above example `dontSaveMe` & `password` are never get serialize as they are declare as a `transient variables`.

Comment: 'Never' is too strong. They are not serialized *by default,* but if you write your own `readObject()/writeObject()` methods you can serialize them yourself.

Answer (score 23):

And a short use - case:
Imagine exposing a User - Object via a public available webservice. 
You sure would like to expose things as nickname, online - state, maybe email or location.
You definitly would not want to expose the password the user uses to login.
Whilst this password could be a property of your User- object,
it should not be serialized e.g. when serializing the object to a JSON - String for the webservice mentioned.

Comment: Very nice use case. I came searching for that only.

Answer (score 7):

`transient` keyword suggests that the object **should not be serialized**, **nor persisted**. You can use it if you don't want to serialize heavy objects (such as `Wrapper`s, for example, which can contain a lot of business logic).

`@Transient` annotation suggests that the object **should not be persisted** (if you've been playing with Hibernate, for example), but it **can be serialized**.

I've included the annotation explanation, because I remember being confused by the two. :-)

Comment: `transient` is only about serialization and its meaning is precisely specified by the JLS. `@Transient` is a 3rd-party defined annotation, and without giving the fully qualified classname it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 3):

`transient` is used to specify which properties of an object will not be saved or ***serialised***. For example, when saving an object to a file, `transient` specifies which properties or attributes will not be saved to that file when that object is saved to a file.

When the object is re-created from the file, the value of that `transient` attribute (or private property) will not be re-created as it was never saved, or serialised to that file. In some cases, you may want to avoid persisting some of these private instance variables or attributes of an object, `transient` allows you to do that.