# Spring Data one to many mapping

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I try to configure **OneToMany** and **ManyToOne** mapping in Spring Data project but have some issues.

So I have two entities: *Employer* and *Project*. One Employer could have many projects.

*Entity classes:*

Employer.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name="Employer")
public class Employer {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq", sequenceName="GLOBAL_SEQUENCE")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE ,generator="my_seq")
    @Column (name="employer_id")
    private int id;

    @Column (name="name")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn (name="employer_id")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<Project> project = new HashSet<Project>();

    ......................
}
```

Project.java

```
@Entity
@Table (name="Project")
public class Project {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name="my_seq", sequenceName="GLOBAL_SEQUENCE")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE ,generator="my_seq")
    @Column (name="project_id")
    private int id;

    @Column (name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="employer_id", nullable = false)
    private Employer employer;
    ......................
}
```

*Repository classes:*

```
public interface EmployerRepository extends JpaRepository<Employer, Integer> {
}

public interface ProjectRepository extends JpaRepository<Project, Integer> {
}
```

*Services:*

```
@Service
public class EmployerServiceImpl implements EmployerService {

    @Autowired
    private EmployerRepository employerRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Employer> getAllEmployers() {
        return employerRepository.findAll();
    }   
}

@Service
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    private ProjectRepository projectRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Project> getAllProjects() {
        return projectRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

*Controller:*

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    private EmployerService employerService;

    private ProjectService projectService;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "employerService")
    public void setEmployerService(EmployerService employerService) {
        this.employerService = employerService;
    }

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier(value = "projectService")
    public void setProjectService(ProjectService projectService) {
        this.projectService = projectService;
    }


    @RequestMapping(value="/employers", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Employer> getEmployers(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name) {
        return employerService.getAllEmployers();        
    }
    ..............................
}
```

*Employer table:*

```
EMPLOYER_ID  .  NAME
......................
1            .  Google
2            .  Oracle
3            .  Facebook
```

*Project table:*

```
PROJECT_ID .    NAME            . EMPLOYER_ID
.......................................
1          . Create web site    .  1
2          . Create reporting   .  2
3          . Create web service .  3
4          . Fixing web site    .  1
```

I'm expecting something like this:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Google","project":[{"id":1,"name":"Create web site"}, {"id":4,"name":"Fixing web site"}},
 {"id":2,"name":"Oracle","project":{"id":2,"name":"Create reporting"}},
 {"id":3,"name":"Facebook","project":{"id":3,"name":"Create web service"}}]
```

But `getEmployers` method from `controller` class return this one:

```
[{"id":1,"name":"Oracle","project":[{"id":4,"name":"Fixing web site",
"employer":{"id":1,"name":"Oracle","project":[{"id":4,"name":"Fixing web site",
"employer":{"id":1,"name":"Oracle","project":[{"id":4,"name":"Fixing web site",
"employer":{"id":1,"name":"Oracle","project":[{"id":4,"name":"Fixing web site",
"employer":{"id":1,"name":"Oracle","project":[{"id":4,"name":"Fixing web site",
"employer":{"id":1,"name":"Oracle","project":[{"id":4,"name":"Fixing web site","employer":
...................
```

Please sorry if this question discussed many times but I didn't find any suitable answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a bi-directional association between `Employer`s and `Project`s.  Additionally, you have configured both sides of the association to be loaded `EAGER`ly (`@ManyToOne` associations are fetched `EAGER`ly by default and you have forced the `@OneToMany` side to be fetched `EAGER`ly as well).  Due to this configuration, when the serialization framework loads the `Employer`s, it finds valid `Project`s that have back-links to the `Employer`s and ends up getting stuck in a cyclic loop.

In order to get the result you want, you will have to mark the `@ManyToOne` side (on the `Project` entity) to be fetched `LAZY`ly as `@ManyTone(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I add `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` to `Project` entity but it doesn't help, the result is the same like the first one.

Comment: It seems that Jackson ends up serializing lazy-loaded entities as well.  [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906985/jackson-do-not-serialize-lazy-objects) has some options you could try.

Comment: I changed my OneToMany mapping to this one:     `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = ("employer"),cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Project> project = new HashSet<Project>();`  but it also doesn't help

Comment: You did not need any configuration on the `employer.projects` property since that was being serialized correctly already.  You need to put `@JsonIgnore` on `project.employer` so that the serialization framework does not try to serialize it.

Comment: As an example, check out [this project from Github](https://github.com/manish-in-java/spring-mvc-sample), run it as `mvn clean tomcat7:run` and then send an `HTTP GET` request to `http://localhost:8080/companies` with `Accept` and `Content-Type` HTTP headers set to `application/json`.  You will get your desired output back as JSON.

Comment: Sorry for delay and thanks for your help! Just adding `@JsonIgnore` to public getter employer object method resolve my issue. I accept your answer, Manish.

Answer (score 2):

Add the @JsonManagedReference In the forward part of the relationship (i.e. User.java class):

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="users_roles",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "user_fk"), inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "role_fk"))
    @JsonManagedReference
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<Role>();

    ...
```

Add the @JsonBackReference In the back part of the relationship (i.e. Role.java class):

```
@Entity
public class Role implements Serializable {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<User>();

    ...
```

This works very well for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the infinite recursion problem with one-to-many mapping, you need to add the `@JsonBackReference` annotation to your `@ManyToOne` field. This allows the JSON serializer to break the infinite loop.