# Lazy Initialized object load without fetch with hibernate Spring

Tags: json, hibernate, spring-mvc, jackson

**SchoolDto**:

```
    @Id
    @Column(name = "c_sm_npk_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "school_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "school_sequence", sequenceName = "t_school_master_c_sm_npk_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="c_sm_vnm_name")
    private String name;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE},fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    UserDto owner;

   /*Many other fileds omit for simplicity with getter/setter methods*/
```

**UserDto**

```
public class UserDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public UserDto() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "c_um_npk_id", nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_sequence")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_sequence", sequenceName = "t_user_master_c_um_npk_id_seq", initialValue = 1, allocationSize = 1)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "c_um_vnm_username", nullable = false)
    private String username;
    @Column(name = "c_um_vnm_email_address")
    private String emailId;
    @JsonSerialize(using = JsonDateSerializer.class)
    @Column(name = "c_um_dnm_birth_date",nullable=false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date birthdate;
    @Column(name="c_um_nnm_age",nullable=false)

    private int age;
    @Column(name = "c_um_vnm_first_name")
    private String firstName;
    @Column(name = "c_um_vnm_last_name")
    private String lastName;
    @Column(name = "c_um_vnm_mobile_number")
    private String mobileNumber;
    @Column(name = "c_um_vnm_gender")
    private String gender;
    @JsonManagedReference("user-role")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userDto", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<RoleDto> roleDtos;
 /* getter setter of properties */
}
```

Here, I have defined owner as Lazy collection. but when I try to find all schools as below:

```
public List<SchoolDto> getAllSchoolsWithAdvanceSearch(SchoolSearchDto schoolSearchDto) {
        return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT s from SchoolDto s").setFirstResult(schoolSearchDto.getFrom()).setMaxResults(schoolSearchDto.getSize()).getResultList();
    }
```

this return list of schools, with all its owner info including roles of the owner (which is again Lazy collection form UserDto) , when I log the hibernate query,I get only one select as below:

```
select
        schooldto0_.c_sm_npk_id as c1_24_,
        schooldto0_.c_sm_vnm_address_line_1 as c2_24_,
        schooldto0_.owner_c_um_npk_id as owner17_24_
    from
        t_school_master schooldto0_
```

during search, I come across that it may be Jackson serialization issue, so I did below changes as per [jackson - do not serialize lazy objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906985/jackson-do-not-serialize-lazy-objects) & [Avoid Jackson serialization on non fetched lazy objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708339/avoid-jackson-serialization-on-non-fetched-lazy-objects) as below

**application-servlet.xml**

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <ref bean="jsonHttpMessageConverter"/>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>


       <bean id="jsonHttpMessageConverter"  class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="objectMapper">
                    <bean class="com.util.HibernateAwareObjectMapper" />
                </property>
            </bean>
```

**HibernateAwareObjectMapper.java**

```
public HibernateAwareObjectMapper() {
        this.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
        Hibernate4Module module = new Hibernate4Module();
        module.configure(Hibernate4Module.Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING, false);
        module.disable(Hibernate4Module.Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
        registerModule(module);
    }
```

Note : I need owner detail later, so I can not mark it as `@JsonIgnore`.

Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance

**Edit :** current output

```
0:  {
       "id": 1
       "name": "school1"
       "address1": null
       owner : {
           "id" : 1,
           "firstName": "Rutesha",
           "lastName" : "Patel",
           "roles":[{
                "name" : "SCHOOL_ADMIN"
            }]
       }
}
```

**Edit :** Expected output

```
0:  {
       "id": 1
       "name": "school1"
       "address1": null
}

OR 

0:  {
       "id": 1
       "name": "school1"
       "address1": null
       owner : null
}
```

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: I have added my question for expected output. it should not load lazy objects initially

Comment: return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT s.id,s.name,s.address1 from SchoolDto s").setFirstResult(schoolSearchDto.getFrom()).setMaxResults(schoolSearchDto.getSize()).getResultList();

Answer (score 0):

Do the following changes

```
return getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT s.id,s.name,s.address1 from SchoolDto s").setFirstResult(schoolSearchDto.getFrom()).setMaxResults(schoolSearchDto.getS‌​ize()).getResultList();
```

`@ManyToOne` - like annotations have according to the documentation the same problem, but in that case it much more likely that the JPA provider will consider the FetchType hint.

```
@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.MERGE},optional = false,fetch=FetchType.LAZY )
UserDto owner;
```

Also following annotations can help.

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "owner")
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@BatchSize(size = 10)
```

Possibly `@JoinColumn(name="other_entity_fk")` should be used.

For Example

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
@JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false)
public Stock getStock() {
    return this.stock;
}
```

Reference [Strategies for Fetch mode](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-fetching-strategies-examples/)

Comment: I tried with this already and I know it works, but later if I add owner in above list than it again gets roles. also there are many fields. so I need something general solution.

Comment: I want to check your POJO, please edit and show. Both School and Owner.

Comment: try putting `optional = false` in `@ManytoOne`

Comment: @Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT) will give you records related to id but i am not able to understand exactly why u are not using `@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)` Because if you want nested objects as a collection there are only two options LAZY and EAGER.

Comment: One side you say I do not want them, and then you need them in future. This is ambiguous. You can Either Fetch them and have null by using Fetchtype.SELECT or can leave as it is.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I was having issue with OpenEntityManagerinView, I found solution from https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate/issues/25