# Force to not serialise non fetched lazy objects in Jackson

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jackson

I don't want to serialise any `lazy` object and tried a lot to get rid of this but no luck. Used

```
mapper.registerModule(new Hibernate5Module())
```

but this seems like loading any lazy object which i don't want.
Have tried many possible ways which i got in net but no luck.

Only thing working for me is `@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)` but again it won't deserialise my data back which I don't want and also in some other condition I need this data back. I mean while I need this object on loaded data I need this object back.

I use:

- Spring boot
- Hibernate 5

Mapping in `POJO`:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
@JsonProperty(value = "parameterValues")
@JsonInclude(value=Include.NON_EMPTY, content=Include.NON_NULL)
private Set<FunctionalAreaParameterValueMaster> masterParameterValues;
```

in controller:

```
return new ResponseEntity<Data>(data, HttpStatus.OK);
```

Comment: I know you wrote that you searched internet but I must ask first. Have you seen: [jackson - do not serialize lazy objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906985/jackson-do-not-serialize-lazy-objects) and [Avoid Jackson serialization on non fetched lazy objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21708339/avoid-jackson-serialization-on-non-fetched-lazy-objects). How it works when you have only single property like `private FunctionalAreaParameterValueMaster masterParameterValues`? Are you sure that you properly configured `ObjectMapper` and it is used during serialisation?

Comment: Yes done it ..... but problem is when am adding Hibernate5Module it is fetching my lazy objects from db which i dont want.I Just want it should not fetch the lazy objects  and do not serialise my lazy data too.It should avoid those and serialise the remaining objects.