# How to implement two way entity reference without recursion, example below

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, reference, entity

I have 2 referenced entity Author and Book and have reference many2one=>one2many between it, i have a problem with realization? when in go to `/authors` i get all authors with his books inside but inside each book have his author (with all own books) and vice versa

Problem in one point, i need get 
`/authors` - all authors without his books
`/author/{id}` with all his books (inside books dont need author) 
`/books` all books with authors inside book (but inside book dont need author)
`/book/{id}` book with author (without his books inside)

```
@Entity(name = "Author")
@Table(name = "authors")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Author {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "author", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Book> books; ....
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Book{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "price")
    private double price;

    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "author_id")
    private Author author; ....
```

Comment: It looks like you need this for json serialization (maybe for a rest endpoint?), did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906985/jackson-do-not-serialize-lazy-objects) post already?

Comment: yeap but answer below are my best way

Comment: My suggestion is not mixing entity and dto in a single class. Using explicit mapping you may get whatever you want without side effects. See my article (in Russian) for more details https://dou.ua/lenta/articles/how-to-use-hibernate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would remove the `private List<Book> books;` from Author and instead create a service:

```
public class BookService {
    public List<Book> getBooks(int authorId) {
        // look up the books by author_id
    }
}
```

Just like a human author doesn't carry all his published books around with him at all times, the Java counterpart shouldn't either.