# How to serialize a game view

Tags: java, swing

I'm designing a game using Swing GUI and MVC method. And I'm trying to add the save and load capabilities to my game GUI. But the View cannot be serialized. So I used transient to define it's instance variable in my Controller. But when I load it the game does not load the view so I get Nullpointerexceptions as I call the instance variable of the game view in the GUI. Is there any solution for that ?

Comment: You should not serialize the view but should serialize the state of the game.

Comment: I do serialize the game state but according to the game state I use the control the view which leads me to using the view in the controller and again a nullpointer

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You should not serialize the view but should serialize the state of the game. You have to make the view [transient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700530/why-use-the-transient-keyword-in-java) to avoid serialization.

When I do serialization usually I have two constructors:

1) One constructor without any parameters that I consider to use when say I create a new Game. I initialize my view in a separate method.

```
Game() {
  initializeView();
}
```

2) Second constructor with state parameter that I consider to use when say I continue a Game. I initialize my view in a separate method.

```
Game(GameState state) {
  initializeView();
  //Restore game state here, I update GUI here
}
```

Comment: I did make it transient and I do serialize the state but I get the nullpointer

Comment: if I initialize the view it's going to be an empty view because I add every element in the view using the controller to add the action listener to it