# defaultWriteObject method in serialization of java is used to read transient variable also if we use it with readObject method

Tags: java, serialization

```
 private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream o)
        throws IOException {  
        o.writeObject(propertyTwo);

        o.defaultWriteObject();  
  }

        private void readObject(ObjectInputStream o)
        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        propertyTwo = (String) o.readObject();
        o.defaultReadObject();
  }
```

Please explain how it serialize transient variable if we use defaultWriteObject and writeObject together?

Comment: You cant serialize transient variables. Please read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700530/why-use-the-transient-keyword-in-java) and accociated links

Comment: @LaxmanChari You can, and this post shows exactly how.

Answer (score 0):

It serializes it *because you serialized it.* Nothing  to do with `defaultWriteObject()` or `defaultReadObject()` whatsoever. They won't serialize `transient` members. But you did.

Comment: But as we know f any variable is marked transient ,then that can not be serialized.

Comment: *Is* not serialized *by default,* unless you serialise it yourself, which is exactly what you have done. 'Cannot be serialized' is not correct.

Comment: Thanks,got it now.