# How to ignore some variables in models using for retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson

I am using **Retrofit** to send and receive requests to my server.

I Have a model like below and I have to send it to my server but some variables in this model have not to send to the server.

```
public class SelectedListModel implements Serializable {

  @SerializedName("p_id")
  @Expose
  private Long pId;

  @SerializedName("p_qty")
  @Expose
  private Double pQty;

  @Expose(serialize = false , deserialize = false)
  private String pName; //Have not to send to server

  @Expose(serialize = false , deserialize = false)
  private String pPrice; //Have not to send to server

  @Expose(serialize = false , deserialize = false)
  private String pImageUrl; //Have not to send to server
}
```

and because of that, I am getting 400 in my responses from the server.
I used of `@Expose(serialize = false, deserialize = false)` in order to Ignore variables that have not to send to the server.
But it doesn't work.
Is there any way to do this or I have to create another model just for my server?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [`transient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.3) keywork for that

```
public class SelectedListModel implements Serializable {

  @SerializedName("p_id")
  @Expose
  private Long pId;

  @SerializedName("p_qty")
  @Expose
  private Double pQty;

  //@Expose(serialize = false , deserialize = false)
  private transient String pName; //Have not to send to server

  //@Expose(serialize = false , deserialize = false)
  private transient String pPrice; //Have not to send to server

  //@Expose(serialize = false , deserialize = false)
  private transient String pImageUrl; //Have not to send to server
}
```

and no need to use `@Expose(serialize = false , deserialize = false)`, into those fields which needed to be excluded.

---

Read [Why does Java have transient fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-fields) and [Why use the `transient` keyword in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20700530/why-use-the-transient-keyword-in-java) for more details.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `transient` keyword to ignore fields when requesting api calls

**JAVA:**

```
transient String name;
```

**KOTLIN:**

```
@Transient
var name: String
```

Answer (score 0):

change your Retrofit adapter code like this (I hope you're using retrofit2)

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
     .excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()
     .create();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()  
     .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
     .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
     .build();
```